# jQuery each loop returns data twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, each

Please, play with teh fiddle below. ONE bug goes as it should  - turns its "head" and crawls in proper direction. But several bugs (starting with two and up) destroy it all. **Jquery "each" returns coordinates twice** so instead of two sets of coordinates for two bugs FOUR are generated.

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    function bug() {
        $('.bug').each(function () {
            //var bugs = $('.bug').length;

            var h = $(window).height() / 2;
            var w = $(window).width() / 2;
            var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
            var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);



            //$this = $(this);
            //var newCoordinates = makeNewPosition();
            var p = $(this).offset();
            var OldY = p.top;
            var NewY = nh;

            var OldX = p.left;
            var NewX = nw;

            var y = OldY - NewY;
            var x = OldX - NewX;
            angle = Math.atan2(y, x);
            angle *= 180 / Math.PI
            angle = Math.ceil(angle);

            console.log(p);

            $(this).delay(1000).rotate({
                animateTo: angle
            });



            $(this).animate({
                top: nh,
                left: nw
            }, 5000, "linear", function () {
                bug();
            });

        });
    };

    bug();
});
```

<s>http://jsfiddle.net/p400uhy2/</s>
http://jsfiddle.net/p400uhy2/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you had .each() calling a function with .each() in it...so each bug had the bug() callback. You just have to move the `bug()` call outside of the .each(){}. See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p400uhy2/2/

Comment: Damn...as usually  - pretty simple solution. Of course!
Thanks , sire!

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by *@Noah B*, the problem is that each *"bug"* is setting the loop for all *"bugs"*.

I'd make `bug()` function per element, so that each *"bug"* can be set individually.

**EDIT** (*@Roko C. Buljan* comment)

```
function bug() {
    // ... your code ...

    // calculate animation time, so that each of bugs runs same fast in long and short distance:
    var top_diff = Math.abs(OldY - nh),
        left_diff = Math.abs(OldX - nw),
        speed = Math.floor(Math.sqrt((top_diff * top_diff) + (left_diff * left_diff))) * 15;

    $(this).animate({
        top: nh,
        left: nw
    }, speed, "linear", function () {
        // rerun bug() function only for that single element:
        bug.call(this);
    });
};

$('.bug').each(bug);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vrhsdops/)

Comment: Than why not `$(".bug").each(bug);`. Than you can always reference inside the `bug` function to `$(this)` like you would normally.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan , Right, got your point. It is never late to learn :)

Comment: Nice edit +1, also nice you've referenced the scope back into `.call`. Although I'd create a more object-oriented way, using `function Bug(){/**/}` and `new Bug()` with `bug.create` and `bug.move` methods, but that's another question :)